# System Monitor Network Speed Not Matching Online Tests

Tags: networking, system-monitor

The upload/download indicated in System Monitor is always about an order of magnitude lower than what is reported by online tests such as
[speedtest.net](http://www.speedtest.net/) or [att.com/speedtest](http://www.att.com/speedtest/)

Does anyone know why this is?

Answer (score 2):

The difference between the network throughput measurements of Gnome System Monitor and the two mentioned online speed tests may be the difference between [bytes](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte) and [bits](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit), because GSM can be configured to display either in units of bits or bytes.

In short: 8 bits make up 1 byte. Hence 8 Megabits (Mb) or 8,000,000 bits, make up 1 Megabyte (MB) or 1000² = 1,000,000 bytes.

To make things more complicated, GSM would display transfer speed in [Mebibyte](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mibiyte) (MiB), which contains 1,024² = 1,048,576 bytes. Even worse, these online speed tests aren't always clear, whether they consider 1 Megabit to be 1000² or 1024² bits.

Comment: I knew that but that does that match either after doing the math.

Comment: No, 8 Megabits make up 10^6 bytes, not 2^20 bytes.

Comment: You're right. I don't know what I was thinking.

Comment: System monitor can be set to read bits or Bytes

Comment: @Jean-Marie: Ok, I addressed that too.

Comment: In GSM 3.16.0 (the latest, I don't have an older version at hand), toggling  bits to bytes changes the prefix from `M` to `Mi` (and `k` to `Ki`), indicating that bits have decimal prefixes and bytes have binary prefixes. I dunno if older versions do that too.

Comment: I meant the online speed tests, but I guess that's not entirely clear. Editing…

Comment: Thank you All. The measures still don't match, but at least I am now matching the units :p